# How to support multiparameter attributes in a rails form object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, multiparameter

I have a form object using the pattern defined here: https://forum.upcase.com/t/form-objects/2267

```
class RegistrationForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth
  ...
end
```

Unlike that example, one of the underlying models in my form has a date field. That date field is being presented as a multiparameter attribute by simple form, and is submitted through to the controller as such:

```
"user"=>
  {"first_name"=>"Hanna",
   "last_name"=>"Macias",
   "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"2016",
   "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"2",
   "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"26",
...
```

However I'm getting a `unknown attribute 'date_of_birth(1i)' for RegistrationForm.` error from `RegistrationForm.new(registration_params)` in the `#create` action on the controller:

```
def create
  @registration = RegistrationForm.new(registration_params)
  if @registration.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def registration_params
  params.require(:registration).permit!
end
```

I've tried defining additional `attr_accessor`s for the `:date_of_birth_1i, :date_of_birth_2i, :date_of_birth_3i`, etc., but that hasn't resolved the issue.

What do I need to do to handle the multiparameter attribute correctly?

Comment: maybe this can help you, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms and also this api page http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html
I believe your params should be something like `params.require(:user).permit(:first_name)`. The best is set a `binding.pry` on this `post` request, then in the console check the `params hash` and how to set the method `registration_params` to include also `first_name`. Maybe you need `params.require("user").permit("first_name")`, test this in the console and see if it retrieves your input

Answer (score 4):

I need to `include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment` as well as `ActiveModel::Model`, and that solved the issue.